# Angular2: Can we access JSON object angular2 application without Interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing application in angular2. If i want to access JSON Object then i must create an interface for it. then my question is - 
Is it possible to access JSON object without using interface? and if YES then are there any problems arise if i neglect interface.

Is it good practice to neglect interface from angular2 application?

Comment: do you mean to see what's the json object contains ?

Comment: its JSON response from server like below
{
    "Car":{
                   "model":"BMW",

Comment: its JSON response from server like below
{
    "Car":{
                   "model":"BMW",
                   "tyre":"MRF"
              }
}

Comment: Personally I'm using `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` to see the json object attributs (you can use the console in the debugger)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a TypeScript question than a Angular question.

By JSON Object I expect you mean the response from a Web Service, such as a Rest service, that in Angular you call with the Http service.

The response for you infact is not a JSON Object, but a JavaScript object. JSON is a serialization of the object -- and it has since been deserialized for you.

Whether or not you NEED to use an interface to access the members of the response object, the answer is No.

You can access its members by casting it to `any`

Whether or not you SHOULD use an interface, that is wholly an option. But many developers who have worked with dynamically and statically typed languages would have the opinion that you should use classes or interfaces to define your Data Transfer Objects.

Much of this can be automated for you, by using tools such as Swagger-Codegen -- or some other code generators for generating your TypeScript Data Transfer Objects.